# Why would running Pex Explorations result in ignoring a previously Pex-generated test method?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, pex

Code being tested:

```
public class TestReader
{
    public string Content { get; private set; }

    public void LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var content = FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName);
        if (!content.StartsWith("test"))
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid file");
        this.Content = content;
    }
}

public static class FileSystem
{
    public static string ReadAllText(string fileName)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }
}
```

Pex method in test project:

```
[PexMethod]
public void CheckValidFileWithPex(string content)
{
    // arrange 
    var fileName = "test.txt";
    Moles_Example.Moles.MFileSystem.ReadAllTextString =
        delegate(string f)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(f == fileName); return content;
        };
    // act 
    var test = new TestReader();
    test.LoadFile(fileName);
    // assert 
    Assert.AreEqual(content, test.Content);
}
```

When I first run "Pex Explorations" on `CheckValidFileWithPex(string content)`, five test methods are generated with the following values for `content`:

1. null
2. ""
3. **"\0\0\0\0"**
4. "test"
5. "\0\0\0\0\0"

However, if I run "Pex Explorations" again, no changes made to the generated tests, existing test project code, or main project prior to second execution, then only 4 tests are listed as generated and the test input from **item 3 ("\0\0\0\0")** is missing.

The source code of the Pex-generated test file still has a test method for this case, but I do not understand why this case is not listed in Pex Exploration Results.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue countless times yesterday and many times this morning... but now I get a list of all 5 test methods every time I run Pex Explorations. Though I have done nothing different to change this behavior, one work around is to delete the Pex-generated source file containing the generated test methods and just run Pex Explorations again.